set of words w such that M halts on w is decidable
I need to prove that the language following language is not turing-recognizable:
$$\text{dec-haltTM} = \{ \langle M\rangle: \text{$M$ is a TM and the set of words that M halts on is decidable}\}$$
I had the following reduction from $\overline{A_{TM}}$ in mind:
"On input $\langle M, w\rangle$ such that $M$ is a TM and $w$ is a string:

build a TM $M'$ on input that on input $x$:
1.1 simulate the run of $M$ on $w$. If the simulated run is accepting, accept $\langle M, w\rangle$.
1.2 else enter a loop.
return $\langle M'\rangle$."

but I'm not sure I can return the output in line 1.1.
I tried to create $M'$ such that if $\langle M,w \rangle$ is in $\overline{A_{TM}}$ then $M'$ doesn't halt on any input thus the language is $\emptyset$ regular and decidable.
If $\langle M,w\rangle$ is in $A_{TM}$, then the set of words  $M'$ halts on is $A_{TM}$, thus not decidable.

You cannot let $M'$ recognize $A_{TM}$ by letting it "accept $\langle M, w\rangle$". You need to define the behaviour of $M'$ on $x$, which you completely ignored.
What you wanted to achieve can be implemented by letting $M'$ recognize an undecidable language $L$ when $M$ accepts $w$, yet does not halt on any input in $\overline{L}$. It is not hard to define the reduction  so that the language $L$ satisfies $L= A_{TM}$, as you wanted. Specifically:
Let $T$ be a fixed TM with $L(T) = A_{TM}$. A reduction from $\overline{A_{TM}}$ to decHaltTM operates as follows. Given input $\langle M, w \rangle$ for the reduction, the reduction outputs $\langle M'\rangle$ that operates as follows. Given input $x$ for $M'$, $M'$ simulates the run of $M$ on $w$. If the simulated run is rejecting, then $M'$ enters a loop. If the simulated run is accepting, then $M'$ simulates the run of $T$ on $x$, and answers the same when $T$ accepts $x$, and otherwise, if $T$ rejects $x$, $M'$ enters a loop.
Regarding correctness, it is not hard to see that if $M$ accepts $w$, then the language of $M'$ is identical to the language of $T$, and thus $L(M') = L(T) = A_{TM}$. Then, as $M'$ is defined so that it does not halt on any input in $\overline{A_{TM}}$, then the set of words it halts on equals its language, in particular, is not decidable. Hence $\langle M'\rangle \notin \text{dec-haltTM}$.
Coversely, if $M$ does not accept $w$, then $M'$ does not halt on any input $x$, and thus the set of inputs that $M'$ halts on is empty, in particular decidable. Hence $\langle M' \rangle \in \text{dec-haltTM}$.

I'm not sure I see the part where M' has the same language as T. What happens if T doesn't halt/ reject x?

In both cases, M' does not halt on x. This guarantees that if T does not accept x, then M' does not halt on x. What makes M' recognize the language of T is the fact that M' answers the same when T accepts x. Meaning, if T accepts x, then M' accepts x as well.
